# Why is it prohibited to show a movie about a dead person?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In Vayikra 19:28, it says

> וְשֶׂרֶט לָנֶפֶשׁ, לֹא תִתְּנוּ בִּבְשַׂרְכֶם

What is wrong with a movie (*seret*) about a dead person, and what does the Torah use "put it in your flesh" to mean watching the movie?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4):

You're translating it incorrectly.

It says

> *v'seret lanefesh, lo titnu bivsarchem*.

This translates to

> movies are for the soul, don't put it in your flesh.

Therefor, do not insert a DVD in your hand - *assur d'oreita*.

Comment: Or it means your mouth is not a DVD drive...

Comment: @Scimonster - well, maybe it is. Maybe I'm secretly Data...